# Método $.POST no actualiza (update mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Intento actualizar mediante una consulta con UPDATE, pero este me envia un error : Cannot convert undefined or null to object.

No entiendo porque se esta generando este error y que es lo que me esta faltando colocar para que el jquery pueda enviar la consulta y se realicen los cambios en la tabla.

tengo una intuición que puede ser en (var json) donde esta el problema, pero aun asi no se como solucionarlo.

dejo los dos codigo que estoy usando para realizar este procedimiento, puede que esten mal o tengan mas de un problema, por favor ayuda.

Codigo Jquery que edita los campos

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Abre el Modal
    $('#modalEditar').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
        var identificador = button.data('identificador')
        var modal = $(this)
        modal.find('.modal-body #identificador').val(identificador)
        
       /*  var imagen = button.data('imagen'); */
        var nombre = button.data('nombre')
        var descripcion = button.data('descripcion')
        var codigo = button.data('codigo')
        var categoria = button.data('categoria')
        var frase_promocional = button.data('frase_promocional')
        var colores = button.data('colores')
        var precio = button.data('precio')
        var disponibilidad = button.data('disponibilidad')
        var promocion = button.data('promocion')
        var fecha = button.data('fecha')

        /* modal.find('.modal-body #url-imagen').val(imagen); */
        modal.find('.modal-body #nombre').val(nombre)
        modal.find('.modal-body #descripcion').val(descripcion)
        modal.find('.modal-body #codigo').val(codigo)
        modal.find('.modal-body #categoria').val(categoria)
        modal.find('.modal-body #frase_promocional').val(frase_promocional)
        modal.find('.modal-body #colores').val(colores)
        modal.find('.modal-body #precio').val(precio)
        modal.find('.modal-body #disponibilidad').val(disponibilidad)
        modal.find('.modal-body #promocion').val(promocion)
        modal.find('.modal-body #fecha').val(fecha)
       
      })

    // Editando la base de datos correspondiente
    $('#editar_btn').click(function() {
        console.log("Editando")

        /* var imagen = $('#modalEditar #url-imagen').val(); */
        var nombre = $('#modalEditar #nombre').val()
        var descripcion = $('#modalEditar #descripcion').val()
        var identificador = $('#modalEditar #identificador').val()

        var codigo = $('#modalEditar #codigo').val()
        var categoria = $('#modalEditar #categoria').val()
        var frase_promocional = $('#modalEditar #frase_promocional').val()
        var colores = $('#modalEditar #colores').val()
        var precio = $('#modalEditar #precio').val()
        var promocion = $('#modalEditar #promocion').val()
        var fecha = $('#modalEditar #fecha').val()

         var json = {
            "columnas": ["nombre", "descripcion","codigo","categoria","frase_promocional","colores","precio", "disponibilidad","promocion","fecha"],
            "valores": [nombre,descripcion,codigo,categoria,frase_promocional,colores,precio,disponibilidad,promocion,fecha ],
            "indice": "id",
            "valor_indice": identificador,
            "tabla": "productos",
        } 
        var url = 'editar.php';
        // metodo post
        $.post({
            url:url , //editar
            data: {'editar': json},
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(respuesta) {
                if (respuesta == 1) {
                    listar_productos();
                    $('#modalEditar').modal('hide')
                } else {
                    console.error("Problemas al editar producto")
                    console.error(respuesta)
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                console.error("Sin Respuesta editar producto");
            }
        });

        

    });
    
});
```

Código PHP UPDATE MYSQL

```
<?php
include_once('conexion.php');

$editar = $_POST['editar'];

//variables 
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
$frase_promocional = $_POST['frase_promocional'];
$colores = $_POST['colores'];
$precio = $_POST['precio'];
$disponibilidad = $_POST['disponibilidad'];
$promocion = $_POST['promocion'];
$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];

    
// UPDATE data
$query = "UPDATE productos SET nombre = '$nombre', descripcion = '$descripcion', codigo = '$codigo', 
categoria = '$categoria', frase_promocional = '$frase_promocional', colores = '$colores', precio = '$precio', disponibilidad = '$disponibilidad', 
promocion = '$promocion', fecha = '$fecha'  WHERE id=$id";
```

Comment: En el php prueba imprimiendo el json $data = json_decode($_POST['editar'],true); echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>"; aver que te sale

Answer (score 0):

Hola no declares todos tus valores solo hazlo con un serialize donde se almacenara todos los datos de tu formulario al hacer el submit a tu boton "editar_btn"

```
$("#editar_btn").submit(function(event) {
        var parametros = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "turl.php",
            data: parametros,
            success: function(datos) {
                alter;
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Y normal lo recibes con tu $_POST['nombre'] y procesas el update

```
$query = "UPDATE productos SET nombre = '$nombre', descripcion = '$descripcion', codigo = '$codigo', categoria = '$categoria', frase_promocional = '$frase_promocional', colores = '$colores', precio = '$precio', disponibilidad = '$disponibilidad', promocion = '$promocion', fecha = '$fecha' WHERE id='$id'";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion,$query );
if($query){
    echo "ACTUALIZO";
}else{
    echo "Fallo";
}
```

Ten cuidado con las comillas en tu php, te recomendaría uses visual studio code para que veas los errores de programación.

Comment: Entonces esto lo tendria que sacar no mas ?

```
   var json = {
            "columnas": ["nombre", "descripcion","codigo","categoria","frase_promocional","colores","precio", "disponibilidad","promocion","fecha"],
            "valores": [nombre,descripcion,codigo,categoria,frase_promocional,colores,precio,disponibilidad,promocion,fecha ],
            "indice": "id",
            "valor_indice": identificador,
            "tabla": "productos",
        } 

```

Comment: El submit no realiza ninguna accion, la ventana modal se queda estatica.

Comment: Comparto codigo : https://codeshare.io/G7Nmwn

Comment: asi deje la conexion de editar.php : https://codeshare.io/5ZNxJo

Comment: me envia un error 500 de la url editar.php

Comment: Para que muestre mensaje debes de poner un div en el modal por ejemplo un div resultados $("#editar_btn").submit(function(event) {
   var parametros = $(this).serialize();
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "tuurl.php",
    data: parametros,
    success: function(datos) {
     listar_productos();
     $("#resultados").html(datos);
     $('#modalEditar').modal('hide');
    }
   });
   event.preventDefault();
  });

Comment: Borra dataType:'json',

Comment: Modifique tu JS https://codeshare.io/G7Nmwn

Comment: Lo coloque tal como editaste el codigo , pero al precionar (boton editar producto del modal), este no se cierra, no hace nada, se queda ahi.

Comment: pero el  var parametros = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(parametros);  que te da la consola

Comment: Faltaba activar el evento submit estaba con click revisa el https://codeshare.io/G7Nmwn

Comment: Se queda congelado el form y no devuelve nada en consola.
te dejo URL : https://slagosh.laboratoriodiseno.cl/came-js/admin.html
Codigo php : https://codeshare.io/21mjq7

Si puedes me editas el codigo php con lo que va correctamente, asi concentrarme solo en el JS que envia los datos. por favor.

Comment: En el modal debes de poner al inicio <form name="editar_btn" id="editar_btn"> y esto al final del boton submit </form>

Comment: pero eso va dentro de modal body?

Comment: este error me da : 
jquery.js:10099 POST https://slagosh.laboratoriodiseno.cl/came-js/editar.php 500
send @ jquery.js:10099
ajax @ jquery.js:9682
(anonymous) @ editar:40
dispatch @ jquery.js:5429
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:5233

Comment: $("#resultados").html(respuesta); modifica esto y el div resultados debes crearlo en el modal o atras del modal

Comment: Borra el id del boton  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Editar producto</button>

Comment: Ahora no tengo ningun error y la consola con el DIV de resultados me dice "actualizo", pero el cambio no se refleja en la celda, ni en la pantalla.

Comment: Realiza un echo a query